# My code refactoring cannot understand by git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010

I have visual studio project, recently i refactor my project, so no code modified, the functions just moved to and from. But my `git extensions`(Visual studio plugin for git) reports lines are deleted in one place and insert in other place.

Why it happen. Is there any way to tell git no changes has been made. because when other developer look the history, it may confuse him.

Comment: You are confused. Refactoring **is** code modification, so the revision control **must** see them. Otherwise, how could other people continue making changes to those files? Revision control tracks the content of files, nothing else. It doesn't distinguish user-visible from internal changes, and you shouldn't try to use it for that.

Comment: How do you imagine those lines *moved*?

Comment: Some change management systems are capable of tracking this kind of modification as a 'move of this block of code'

Comment: @andy256 I use araxis merge, even though not perfect, but i detect these changes, and never show these are differences

Comment: My fault for asking a rhetorical question. The point is, the lines *were* deleted from one location and inserted at another. git is just reporting what happened.

Comment: @andy256  the point is that git looses track of the code history, but other tools are able to track these changes as a move, preserving the history of that block of code.

Comment: @Ptolemy Git can too, as long as the move was atomic they would be part of one changeset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code refactoring is part of code's modification. There is no way for git to skip these, as file contents change.

To avoid confusing other developers, you should separate code refactoring commits from functional changes.

Comment: Am i create new branch?

Comment: This is a 'limitation' of git.  Git can handle moves of files, as long as you move the file using **git mv**  but what git does not cope with (to the best of my knowledge) are 'moves of blocks of code' from one file to another (or even around the same file

Comment: You can use the git commit comment to explain what was done. "Refactoring only". If tests pass before and after the refactoring, then you're good, right?